# It is possible to change the name of the DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table in Liquibase?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

It is possible to change the name of the DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table in Liquibase?

I hoped that it could be in a application.yml file, but I did not find such a property in the documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the value of Liquibase's 'log lock' table name by passing a JVM system property named `liquibase.databaseChangeLogLockTableName`. For example:

```
-Dliquibase.databaseChangeLogLockTableName=MY_LOG_LOCK_TABLE_NAME
```

Spring Boot's integration with Liquibase does not support this property, so you cannot define this as a Spring property and have Spring Boot propagate it to Liquibase. The Liquibase properties which Spring Boot *does* suport are listed [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseProperties.java) but you have already spotted these. Until Spring Boot does support propagating this property I think you'll have to supply it via the command line.

FWIW, the Maven plugin for Liquibase does support this via the optional parameter: `databaseChangeLogLockTableName`. More details [in the docs](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/generated/update-mojo.html#databaseChangeLogLockTableName).